# p:selectCheckboxMenu uncheckAll not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{analyticsController.cleanFleet}"
     update="filtersForm-heatmap"
     onclick="PF('wvHeatmapOrganization').uncheckAll();
              PF('wvHeatmapOrganization').selectValue(null);"
     styleClass="btnCleanAnalytics">
         <h:outputText value="#{msg['ANALYTICS-clear']}" />
         <i class="pi pi-trash"></i>
</p:commandLink>
```

And the selectCheckBoxMenu:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="organizations"
       value="#{analyticsController.refOrganizationsSelected}"
       filter="true"
       filterMatchMode="contains"
       multiple="true"
       scrollHeight="250"
       widgetVar="wvHeatmapOrganization"
       showCheckbox="true" styleClass="customInput manymenu-advanced" >
             <f:selectItems value="#{analyticsController.userOrganizations}"
                            var="organization"
                            itemLabel="#{(organization.commercialName eq null) ?  null :  '[ '.concat(organization.id).concat('] ').concat(organization.name) } "
                            itemValue="#{organization.id}"/>
                               <p:ajax event="change" process="@this"/>
                               <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{analyticsController.addOrganizations()}"/>
                               <p:ajax event="change"  listener="#{analyticsController.updateFilters()}"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

I need clear the component with nothing selections by my actual result is this:

[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYWyz.png)

Please could you help me? How I can clean the selected items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear the current selected items, you can clear the "refOrganizationsSelected" list using the action from your commandLink in the backend and later, update the selectCheckboxMenu component.

Eg with cities:

```
<h:form id="citiesForm">

    <p:commandLink action="#{helloWorld.clean}"
                   update="organizations"
                   styleClass="btnCleanAnalytics">
        <h:outputText value="Clear" />
    </p:commandLink>


    <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="organizations"
                          value="#{helloWorld.citiesSelected}"
                          filter="true"
                          filterMatchMode="contains"
                          multiple="true"
                          scrollHeight="250"
                          widgetVar="wvHeatmapOrganization"
                          showCheckbox="true" styleClass="customInput manymenu-advanced" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{helloWorld.cities}" />
    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
</h:form>
```

and the backend:

```
 public void clean() {

    citiesSelected = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

After that, selectCheckboxMenu will not have any selected item.

Comment: Thanks for answer, this solved the problem

Comment: @JohanSmith then please accept the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers